# spotipy auth workflow results in error=state_mismatch in browser

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, spotify, spotipy

I am attempting to run through the Spotify authentication workflow via `spotipy` and it's `prompt_for_user_token` utility. I am following the directions [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/), the official Spotify web API tutorial, verbatim from what I can tell. And using the examples from Paul Lamere's Spotipy project [here](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/tree/master/examples)

I have a premium Spotify account and a registered application with a client id and client secret (both 32 character strings) and the redirect URI given in the example (`...//localhost:8888/callback`). all shown on my application page (`...//developer.spotify.com/my-applications`)

Start my application server from `app.js` the "authentication_code" example in the tutorial (which has been modified to contain my app's client id, client secret, and redirect URI).

```
$node app.js 
Listening on 8888
```

after exporting my app's `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET`, and `REDIRECT_URI` into my environment as described in the tutorial, I run the `user_playlists.py` example script from Paul Lamere's `spotipy` examples with my username (really user "id" - 9 digit number) as it's only command line argument.

The browser (chrome) has opened previously with the option to log in to Spotify via Facebook or password. I choose Facebook and I then get a browser alert that reads:

```
localhost:8888 says:
There was an error during the authentication.
```

With the browser url at:

```
...localhost:8888/#error=state_mismatch
```

And the `prompt_for_user_token` function never returns. Every time I run the example script now the browser opens, but to a blank page, with the same browser alert and URL.

Is it obvious to anyone what I'm doing wrong or how to find out what the nature or any details of the authentication error are or how to resolve the `state_mismatch` error or even what it means?

Comment: off topic but concerning your mysql question yesterday, check over halfway down this self-answer of mine for the password in the error log file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025524

Comment: :-o Wow! That certainly is a thorough answer @Drew! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great and basic example of spotify oauth workflow via spotipy which doesn't depend on node or util.prompt_for_user_token [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973812/2403318) contributed by perelin.

In addition the spoti**py** documentation does not indicate which of several user level scopes is required for any given spoti**py** method which would be helpful. But moreover it's a good idea to understand [scopes](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/) before you start writing client code for spotify. For example: "playlist-read-private" is required for user_playlists as opposed to, "user-library-read", which isn't made clear in the spoti**py** documentation so you need to look at the official spotify web api documentation and be aware of which scope your spoti**py** method will (probably) require.