# (spotipy) method never completes because it ends up at oauth redirect url's view

Tags: django, oauth, spotipy

I am trying to use spotipy to execute a search request from Spotify. I specified the client id, secret id and redirect url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/q) in my bash_profiles, as described in the API.

```
def search(username, query):

    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope) #like oauth with redirect url
    print("received token response")

    if token:
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
        return sp.search(query, 1, 0, type='track')
```

The problem is I am using django, which also forces me to specify the redirect url in my urls.py and a corresponding view in views.py

```
    [from urls.py...]
    url(r'^callback/q$', views.callback, name='callback'),

    [from views.py...]
    def callback(request):
        print("callback view reached")
        return render(request, 'rec/search.html')
```

It seems like django then intercepts displays the view from the redirect-url, so my search method never finishes executing. I am a little confused on how I get a token that requires a redirect url, yet then continue executing the rest of the method that follows the authorization request

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. What does your bash_profile have to do with anything? Why are you *prompting* for a token in a web app?

Comment: that's how the Spotipy api works. You use a util method to get a token, create a spotify object and call methods on it. For the bash profile-- you can choose to export the variables (like i did) or pass them as args to the auth method

Comment: to be more specific on the "user prompting". it does open up a page on spotify and the user has to agree to give certain privileges. i believe that is first time auth only, not on refresh tokens

Comment: @tara did you ever figure it out? Facing similar issues myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps but I abandoned authentication via util.prompt_for_user_token in favor of [this basic implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973812/2403318). It's implemented in bottle but should be relatively easy to translate to django and your specific needs. I'm hoping to do the same.

Comment: thank you! will see what i can do with this and add here if i find anything additional to be of use. though am still very curious what i was doing wrong, as it seems like auth-with-redirect is a common pattern. i had a little better luck splitting the auth token out into a separate method but still was not up to working 100%